# Listing objects by date

Tags: list, sorting, date, python-3.x, datetime

So, I have a list of objects, it looks like this:

```
ID    Date

1     15/11/2009
2     11/06/2010
3     11/09/2015
4     12/08/2013
5     09/08/2011
6     11/10/2012
7     11/10/2014
```

Now, I want to sort that list of objects by its date. I have tried `sorted(list,key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%m-%Y'))`, tried `list.sort()`, tried all kind of different things, but it simply doesnt sort.

Can somebody help me?

Object looks like this:

```
class X:

    id = None
    date = None

    def __init_(self, id, date):
        self.id = id
```

Comment: what is x, I think it is a tuple and so you have to use x[0] in your strptime function but I am not sure if x is a tuple or not so you might start out by printing x to see what it is and also do a type(x)

Comment: What type is the list item (e.g., tuple, string)?

Comment: @JasonM.Owens please see edited answer

Comment: still not clear, is date an attribute of x and is the list you are trying to sort a list of instances of x?  If you are controlling the creation of x and the date is assigned at instatiation then it seems this should be much easier so you need to provide more clarity on x

Comment: Please show the _actual_ list of objects to be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

According to the list, the date input format is: dd/mm/yyy so the strptime method expects the format argument to match the input, therefore '%d/%m/%Y' should be passed to strptime.  Note: capital %Y expects yyyy and lower-case %y expects yy.

Hope this helps!

Try this:

```
import datetime
dates = ['15/11/2009',
     '11/06/2010',
     '11/09/2015',
     '12/08/2013',
     '09/08/2011',
     '11/10/2012',
     '11/10/2014']


sorted_dates = sorted(dates, key=lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%Y'))
#This just print the dates for verification
for v in sorted_dates:
    print(v)
```

Comment: You are not accounting for id

Comment: Hum! I never saw the ID column, better check my eye sight.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list looks something like this:

```
objects = [
   (1, datetime.datetime(1999, 12, 13, 0, 0)),
   (2, datetime.datetime(1992, 4, 29, 0, 0)),
   (3, datetime.datetime(2001, 5, 23, 0, 0))]
```

You should be able to use the seconds of a datetime.timedelta to write a comparison function:

```
def cmp_objects(tuple_a, tuple_b):
    t_delta = tuple_a[1] - tuple_b[1]
    return int(t_delta.total_seconds())

sorted_objects = sorted(objects, cmp_objects)
```

I believe the main issue you were running into is that comparisons of tuples or (date) strings is handled *lexicographically* (alphabetical) but you would prefer a numerical comparison. The `cmp_objects` function references the datetime object stored in your tuple, then does math to compare two dates as integers.